# Footer stick to bottom, Extends beyond page

Tags: html, css

Trying to make the footer stick to the bottom and the content become automatically centered in between the header and footer.

Currently using this technique: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

But my footer appears way below and creates a huge gap in between.

Website: Stingrayimages.ca

Edit: So i managed to get the footer to stick to the bottom.  However, the footer is not at the bottom of the page, it leaves a little bit of a scroll. And when shrink the window, the footer doesnt stop where the content.

Also i cant get the content div to stay in the middle without messing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Your container div should wrap your Head div.  I think you mistook Ryan's head area for what designers commonly refer to as the header of the page, when in fact in the example it's the head element of the html.  The extra space on the bottom is likely equal to the height of your head div.

In the sticky footer, remember, the container wraps all body content but the footer.

Comment: But im trying to keep the content centered between the head and footer.  the container has a width but the header needs to have a continuous width as you can see.

Comment: The problem is that for CSS to be able to do vertical aligning, it has to have a known parent height.  For example, you could put in a parent div of 500px and a child div inside with vertical-align:center and it would be centered at 250.  But, in this example, your container div is never going to be a defined height because it varies by screen.  So, doing perfect vertical positioning on sticky footer isn't going to happen.  You can fudge it for --most-- screens, but perfect isn't an option here.  And it's not what the solution is meant to accomplish, just glue the foot to the bottom.

Comment: Alright so put the head inside the container now.  I dont know why the footer is still all the way beyond the page.  Now how would i center the content div in the middle?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the same technique as the link, you are missing position at the footer.

And still, with the example you linked, see the structure:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

But i would rather go with something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

div#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%; /* IE6: min-height*/
    min-height: 100%;
}

div#header {

}

div#content {
    padding: 1em 1em 5em;
}

div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work!  Footer MUST go outside the container for this solution to work.

Comment: Not exactly.  One of the principles of sticky footer is having the center "content" area fill between the header and the footer.  Yours grows with content, but doesn't fill through.  So, if the user was trying to do a repeating background on the content area, it would only reach as far as the content does.  The genius of sticky footer is that it's NOT using absolute positioning.

Comment: Then it depends on how you understand sticking footers? See the link OP refers to, they does it exactly the way i posted. Sticking footer does not have to be visible all the time, but can follow the content.

Comment: Put different colors on the header, footer, and content sections and you'll see what I mean.  If you replicate the tutorial exactly, the body will fill the position between the header and footer.  Yours will have white space between the content section and the footer.  That's the difference between going absolute vs relative positioned.  The footer will always push off if you have a ton of body content.

Comment: I still can see what you're point is. I did some code, that show a header, content and footer area. Now with colors (http://jsfiddle.net/xgZgd/10/). The footer is positioned at the bottom of the screen at all times, but if their is too much content it will go to the bottom of the scroll. Why is that not the answer to OP? It is exactly what he was refering to with the link.

Comment: So i kinda got it to work, its sticking to the bottom but i can still scroll a bit. and i cant seem to get the middle div to center in the middle

Comment: Which example did you go with? Can i see the code / site where you are at right now?

Comment: @designer www.stingrayimages.ca

Comment: Well as i can see you are having some troubles because of the attribute margin on p-tags. You can either remove this, and then use padding to adjust the position or you can adjust it by set margin -5.5em on container div. I would remove the margin on paragraph in the footer div. #footer p { margin: 0; }

Comment: @Resz did you solve it? I would appreciate some kind of response. Maybe by accept my answer - which can give other with the same question the help, too :)